# Python bowling program dictionary from text file

Tags: python, file

Below is my assignment.  I am stuck on how to include the total in the dictionary.  I am not even sure if this is possible but I need it to do the average.  I would appreciate a push in the right direction.   :)

Assignment:Write a program that will read an unknown number of bowlers and their bowling scores (with possible values from 1 to 300) from an external file called "bowlingscores.txt".  The file will look similar to the following:

```
David
102
Hector
300
Mary
195
Jane
160
Sam
210
```

Output the bowlers’ names to an external data file called "bowlingaverages.txt". Next to each bowler's name, print a message dependent on their scores:
For perfect scores (equal to 300), output “perfect”
For those scores greater than the average score, output “above average”
For those below average, output “below average”

```
scores = {}  
total = 0


def bowl_info(filename):
    infile = open("bowlingscores.txt", "r")

    for line in infile:    
        if line.strip().isdigit():
            score = int(line)
            scores[name] = score
            total += score    
        else:
            name = line.strip()
    return  scores




bowl_info("bowlingscores.txt")
numbowlers = len(scores)
total = 0
average = total / numbowlers
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Would it not be possible to simply add the total as a key in the dictionary and update it in the loop as you have done?

```
scores = {'total': 0}  


def bowl_info(filename):
    infile = open("bowlingscores.txt", "r")

    for line in infile:    
        if line.strip().isdigit():
            score = int(line)
            scores[name] = score
            scores['total'] += score    
        else:
            name = line.strip()
    return  scores




bowl_info("bowlingscores.txt")
numbowlers = len(scores)
#total = 0 REMOVE THIS LINE
average = scores['total'] / numbowlers
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `score` as well `total`,

```
def bowl_info(filename):
    total = 0 # you have to define toatl within function.
    .. 
    ..
    return  scores, total
```

Catch both object through function call  and use it in your code:-

```
scores, total = bowl_info("bowlingscores.txt")

#score = {'Jane': 160, 'Hector': 300, 'Mary': 195, 'Sam': 210, 'David': 102}
#total = 967
```

Comment: I got it to do what you did but when I call the function and try to get the average, total is not defined.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  I am gonna sleep on it.  :)  Thank you!!!!

Comment: @Holly define total with in funtion i updated the code check it.

Answer (score 0):

check and analyze it, i covered all the you want:

```
>>> my_dict ={}
>>> f = open('bowlingscores.txt')
>>> for x in f:
...     my_dict[x.strip()] = int(f.next())   # f.next() moves the file pointer to nextline and return is value
... 
>>> my_dict
{'Jane': 160, 'Hector': 300, 'Mary': 195, 'Sam': 210, 'David': 102}
>>> total_score = sum(my_dict.values())   
>>> total_score
967
>>>avg = float(total_score/len(my_dict.values()))
193.0
>>> for x,y in my_dict.items():
...     if y == 300:
...         print x,y,"Perfect"
...     elif y >=avg:
...         print x,y,"Above Average"
...     elif y <= avg:
...         print x,y,"Below Average"
... 
Jane 160 Below Average
Hector 300 Perfect
Mary 195 Above Average
Sam 210 Above Average
David 102 Below Average
```